# Dosen 't get collection when refreshing page - AngularFire

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angularfire

I'm having a problem when I refresh the page it dosen 't initialize my call in my constructor.

I've been using this for a guide:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gUmItHaVL2w&ab_channel=TraversyMedia
https://github.com/angular/angularfire

**EDIT:**

For getting it to work again I have to go to another page and hit refresh and go back then it calls it correctly.

**schedule.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import {ScheduleInterface} from '../../models/schedule';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {AuthService} from '../auth/auth.service';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ScheduleService {
  schedulesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<ScheduleInterface>;
  schedules: Observable<ScheduleInterface[]>;
  scheduleDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<ScheduleInterface>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, private authService: AuthService) {
    console.log('scheduleService called1');
    this.schedulesCollection = this.afs.collection('schedules', ref => ref
      .where('UID', '==', this.authService.currentUserId)
      .orderBy('user', 'asc'));
    console.log('scheduleService called2');
    this.schedules = this.schedulesCollection.snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(map(changes => {
        console.log('scheduleService called3');
        return changes.map(a => {
          // doesn't get called when page gets refreshed
          console.log('scheduleService called4');
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as ScheduleInterface;
          data.docRef = a.payload.doc.id;
          return data;
        });
      }));
  }

  getSchedules() {
    return this.schedules;
  }
```

**Console**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not subscribing to the observable. Move the logic for fetching data out of the constructor and into a method returning an observable.

```
   getSchedules(): Observable<ScheduleInterface> {
        return this.afs
            .collection("schedules", (ref) =>
                ref
                    .where("UID", "==", this.authService.currentUserId)
                    .orderBy("user", "asc")
            )
            .snapshotChanges()
            .pipe(
                map((changes) => 
                    changes.map((a) => {
                        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as ScheduleInterface;
                        data.docRef = a.payload.doc.id;
                        return data;
                    })
                )
            );
    }
```

Inject the service in the component you would like to get the schedules in, and invoke the getSchedules method in the service from there.

```
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {

        constructor(protected scheduleService: ScheduleService){}

        ngOnInit(): void {
            this.scheduleService.getSchedules().subscribe(result => {
                console.log(result);
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you’re getting the first value, when schedules is still null. Try this:

```js
get mySchedules() { return this.schedules }
```

Or don’t call the method at all, use just `scheduleService.schedules`.